# Using An Image View In Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am trying to setup an image view in my Main.Storyboard so that I can update it in my app extension. I am struggling to work out how to get the code to initialise the Image View. I feel so stupid for not being able to figure this out.

In Xcode, I am used to linking it by dragging the constructor (if that's what it's called) into the app code.

How is this accomplished in Xamarin?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the storyboard, select the UIImageView. Then in the properties window (on the right, usually) there is a `Name` property. That creates an outlet to your view controller class with UIImageView. You can access it in the `ViewDidLoad` method (that's the earliest it's guaranteed to be initialized) and setup the UIImageView however you need.

See this screenshot showing the Name property:

[image]